# Why ReSharper Code Cleanup removes all using static directives

Tags: c#, resharper

I literally want to use using static directive in my code , but when I run ReSharper Code Cleanup it removes all using static directives for no apparent reason.I couldn't find a setting to stop that.

Comment: Have you tried this one? https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0iat.png

Comment: Actually it is not ReSharper if i remove Fix Style Cop Violations it doesn't remove them but the strange thing is that there is no stylecop violation when I use using static

Comment: Maybe you should update your question and it’s tags with this new info

Comment: I got the same problem and has filed an issue.
https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop.ReSharper/issues/38